# Why there's no "then" in async functions

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have two identical functions in terms of outcome:

```
const p1 = async () => {
  return 1;
};

const p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(1);
});

console.log(typeof p1.then);
console.log(typeof p3.then);
```

I would have expected that both would transpile to have a "then" property but it appears they do not:

[image]

But yet vs-code's intellisense notes them as both being promises:

[image]

[image]

and we can even ensure the return type is the same if we're explicit about **p3**:

[image]

Now I *think* by definition a Promise is "then*able*" right? The reason I find myself caring is that I have an inferred interface in Typescript from the following function:

```
export const DELAYED = "WAIT_IN_PARALLEL_DELAYED";
export function delayed<T = any>(delayedPromise: () => Promise<T>) {
  return {
    delayed: DELAYED,
    start(resolve, reject) {
      delayedPromise()
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
    }
  };
}
```

I'd have thought passing in:

```
 const test = () => async() => 1;
```

to the function `delayed(test)` would be fine but instead it is complaining that test does NOT have ".then". Can someone help me understand the flaw in my thinking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for starters, no, `p1` and `p3` are not the same. `p3` is a `Promise`, so it does have a `then` method. But `p1` is a **function that returns a promise**, so it is not a promise, but a function, and as such does not have a `then` property, just like in `const p4 = () => 5` `p4` is a function, not a `number`.

Effectively, your `delayed` function requires you to pass a function that returns a `Promise`, though I am not sure why. Shouldn't be easier to just pass the `Promise` itself? But, anyway, your `test` function does not match the type of `delayedPromise`. Why?

Because, in your definition:

```
delayedPromise: () => Promise<T> // a function that returns Promise<T>
const test = () => async() => 1; // a function that returns a function that returns a Promise
```

You should define `test` as

```
const test = async() => 1;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It does help. My problem seems to be a lack of breaks from the monitor. Everything you say makes sense and now that I've gone for a run I'm sure life will return to normal.

Comment: Both answers are correct but due to your verbosity I've decided to mark yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why there's no “then” in async functions

Async functions **return** a promise when called (they are not promises themselves). That promise has a `then` property.

Comment: Omg. I guess time to take a break from the monitor. So obvious from 10ft but I've been attempting to solve the problem from 2ft for too long. Thanks for the push. :)